# Return byte array from C# to Java using UnmanagedExports and JNA

Tags: java, c#, arrays, unmanaged, jna

I recently found the library [UnmanagedExports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) that allowed me to access C#-methods directly from Java using [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna).

Has anyone an idea about what is wrong with my attempt to return a byte array from C# to Java?

Here is my example:

C# code:

```
using System;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
namespace JnaTestLibrary
{
  public class JnaTest
  {
    [DllExport]
    public static byte[] returnT1()
    {
        byte[] t1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
        return t1;
    }
  }
}
```

Java code:

```
package me.mt.test;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;
public class JnaTest {
  public interface JnaTestInterface extends Library{
      byte[] returnT1();
  }
  static JnaTestInterface jnaTest = null;

  static{       
        if(Platform.is64Bit()){
            jnaTest = (JnaTestInterface)Native.loadLibrary("JnaTestLibrary64", JnaTestInterface.class);
        }
        else{
            jnaTest = (JnaTestInterface)Native.loadLibrary("JnaTestLibrary86", JnaTestInterface.class);
        }
    }

  public byte[] returnT1(){
      return jnaTest.returnT1();
  }
}
```

Java exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported return type class [I in function returnT1
```

Comment: I do not know a lot about jna, but I believe that ByteBuffers (specifically the direct variant) can be used to pass byte arrays across native boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using pointers.

C# code:

```
using System;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
namespace JnaTestLibrary
{
  public class JnaTest
  {
    [DllExport]
    public unsafe static byte* returnT1()
    {
        byte[] t1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
        fixed (byte* p1 = t1)
        {
          return p1;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Java code:

```
package me.mt.test;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
public class JnaTest {
  public interface JnaTestInterface extends Library{
      Pointer returnT1();
  }
  static JnaTestInterface jnaTest = null;

  static{       
        if(Platform.is64Bit()){
            jnaTest = (JnaTestInterface)Native.loadLibrary("JnaTestLibrary64", JnaTestInterface.class);
        }
        else{
            jnaTest = (JnaTestInterface)Native.loadLibrary("JnaTestLibrary86", JnaTestInterface.class);
        }
    }

  public byte[] returnT1(){
      Pointer p1 = jnaTest.returnT1();
      return p1.getByteArray(0, 5);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the pointed-to data could get clobbered by a CLR garbage collection between `jnaTest.returnT1()` and `p1.getByteArray(0, 5)`.

Comment: @TomBlodget The `unsafe` keyword doesn't change the semantics of ordinary code at all. Until now everything works fine.

Comment: You're banking on luck. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10076954/2226988). The basic problem is memory ownership and, depending on the technique, transfer of ownership. You are using memory after giving ownership back to the CLR—outside the scope of the `fixed` statement.